# Send m-search packets on all network interfaces

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, assertion, reactor, ssdp

I am implementing a code through which i have to get devices connected to all network interfaces on my machine.

For this, i am first getting the ip of all network interfaces and then sending m-search command on them.

After 2.5 seconds port is stopped to listen.

But it is giving me some assertion error.

`Code:`

```
class Base(DatagramProtocol):
    """ Class to send M-SEARCH message to devices in network and receive datagram
        packets from them
    """
    SSDP_ADDR = "239.255.255.250"
    SSDP_PORT = 1900
    MS = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: {}:{}\r\nMAN: 'ssdp:discover'\r\nMX: 2\r\nST: ssdp:all\r\n\r\n".format(SSDP_ADDR, SSDP_PORT)

def sendMsearch(self):
    """ Sending M-SEARCH message
    """
    ports = []
    for address in self.addresses:
        ports.append(reactor.listenUDP(0, self, interface=address))

    for port in ports:
        for num in range(4):
            port.write(Base.MS, (Base.SSDP_ADDR,Base.SSDP_PORT))
        reactor.callLater(2.5, self.stopMsearch, port) # MX + a wait margin


def stopMsearch(self, port):
    """ Stop listening on port
    """
    port.stopListening()
```

`Error:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "work\find_devices.py", line 56, in sendMsearch
    ports.append(reactor.listenUDP(0, self, interface=address))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\posixbase.py", line 374, in listenUDP
    p.startListening()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\udp.py", line 172, in startListening
    self._connectToProtocol()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\udp.py", line 210, in _connectToProtocol
    self.protocol.makeConnection(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\protocol.py", line 709, in makeConnection
    assert self.transport == None
AssertionError
```

Please tell what's wrong in this code and how to correct this.

Also on linux machines, if no device is found on network then it doesn't go to stopMsearch() why ?

Comment: Of the top of my head I recommend printing out the addresses that are being passed to the `interface` argument of `reactor.listenUDP` and see if that offers a clue.  I'm also confused about trying to listen on port 0, have you tested that?

Comment: @MikeLutz I have checked the addresses, they are correct and if i send m-search individually on them, they work fine. Problem is when i am trying to send m-search on all of them at the same time.

Comment: I can't think of any obvious problem given your code snippets because of how much is unknown (I suspect most readers will have the same response too - there is a vast amount of detail that isn't addressed in your sample).  Consider documenting your debugging experiments (I.E. things like the address check, and include simplified working and non-working runnable code) in this question.  Help us better understand the scope of your code/problem -with examples- and we will be able to offer higher quality feedback/answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A protocol can only have one transport.  The loop:

```
for address in self.addresses:
    ports.append(reactor.listenUDP(0, self, interface=address))
```

tries to create multiple UDP transports and associate them all with `self` - a single protocol instance.

This is what the assertion error is telling you.  The protocol's transport must be `None` (ie, it must not have a transport).  But on the second iteration through the loop, it already has a transport.

Try using multiple protocol instances instead.

Comment: @JeanPaul are u saying to modify code like this - `def sendMsearchToAll(self):   for address in self.addresses:     self.sendMsearch(address)         def sendMsearch(self, address): port = reactor.listenUDP(0, self, interface=address) for num in range(4):    port.write(Base.MS, (Base.SSDP_ADDR,Base.SSDP_PORT))   reactor.callLater(2.5, self.stopMsearch, port) # MX + a wait margin`

Comment: That is ... hard to read.  But no, I don't think that's right.  I still only see one instance of `Base` (I think - again, hard to read).

Comment: @JeanPaul yes, i have still used one instance of Base and that is wrong. But now i have implemented code with seperate Base instance for each interface and it worked. Thanks Jean-Paul

Comment: @JeanPaul on linux machines, if no device is found on network then its not calling stopMsearch()   why ? how to debug this ?

Comment: There's no device finding code in your question.  I'm not sure what you're talking about.  Maybe you want to open a new question.

Comment: ... please don't do that.  Please use stackoverflow.

Comment: @JeanPaul i have posted new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531442/get-media-renderer-devices-from-all-networks-connected-to-a-machine-using-twiste)